Can we mix 32GB CL20 with 16GB CL22?
I have a laptop with AMD 5800H and RTX 3060, I have a 16GB CL22 3200Hz stick, and I have another 32GB CL20 3200Hz stick. Can I use this configuration?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

It is possible to combine RAM modules with different capacities and latencies, but there are some things to remember to ensure compatibility and good performance:
When you mix RAM modules with different CAS latencies (such as CL20 and CL22), the system will usually preset to a higher latency (CL22 in this case). This will slow down performance slightly but will not cause any serious problems. For example, if you mix a 3200 MHz CL20 module with a 3200 MHz CL22 module, both will run at 3200 MHz but the timing will match the slower module (CL22). The same voltage is needed to avoid safety problems.
